# PHPExcel putting string date into .xls

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

guys. I have dates at DB as strings "d/m/Y".
When I put this dates into Excel, it shows me normal dates like 03/10/2000, but when I click on the cell, it show me the value  `'03/10/2000`. So, the value is string, and not date as required for me.

So, I transformed the date from DB to a PHP date object and get sure with `var_dump` that date is Date object with that code :

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $array[$i-20]['Date']);
              $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

but anyway, the values in generated .xls are with  `'` before value.

Why it appears and how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Excel stores dates as a serialized timestamp, the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if using the Mac calendar). To store a value as a date (and not simply as a string), you need to convert your string date to a serialized timestamp, and then set the format mask for the cell.

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $array[$i-20]['Date']);
$excelDate = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($date);
```

Set $excelDate as the cell value

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C11', $excelDate );
```

and then apply the format mask to that cell

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('C11')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);
```

The [02types.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/02types.php#L94) example script in the [`/Examples` folder](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples) demonstrates this

**EDIT**

You can (and it's more efficient to) apply a style  to a range of cells: just specify the range in the `getStyle()` call.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('C11:C200')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);
```

To get details of available format: PHPExcel has a number of pre-defined formats built-in, and those can be found as constants in [Classes/PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php#L43). However, you're not limited to that set of formats; and (in the same way that MS Excel lets you define "custom" formats) you can simply pass a string defining the format (e.g. "d-mmm-yyyy") using pretty much any of the [rules that can be used for MS Excel number format masks](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e) as the format

Comment: It works, thanks. Can you just say how to apply that format to a range, and also, where to find informaton about all available formats for currency, numbers, percents, and so on? 
Thanks!

Comment: Amazed by the knowledge. +1

Comment: @new_newB1e - Edited my answer to include a response to those additional questions

Comment: @AlivetoDie -  Knowledge comes from having written the library